# The navigation prop is missing for this navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Every single example I have seen in Stack Overflow uses the case where the `App` component is a functional component, but I am using a class-based `App` component and I am playing catch up with the breaking changes of React Navigation.

This is my code inside `App.js` file:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import {
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createStackNavigator
} from "react-navigation";

import AuthScreen from "./screens/AuthScreen";
import WelcomeScreen from "./screens/WelcomeScreen";
import MapScreen from "./screens/MapScreen";
import DeckScreen from "./screens/DeckScreen";
import SettingsScreen from "./screens/SettingsScreen";
import ReviewScreen from "./screens/ReviewScreen";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
      welcome: WelcomeScreen,
      auth: AuthScreen,
      main: {
        screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
          map: MapScreen,
          deck: DeckScreen,
          review: {
            screen: createStackNavigator({
              review: ReviewScreen,
              settings: SettingsScreen
            })
          }
        })
      }
    });
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MainNavigator />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

I was refactoring it along nicely and then it broke with this message that I cannot figure out:

> Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this
>   navigator. In react-navigation 3 you must set up your app container
>   directly.

Yes, I looked at React Native docs regarding `AppContainer` and I saw this line of code

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

but I am not sure how to refactor mines or not refactor it too much to get this right.

When I try to add this line of code `export default createAppContainer(App);` at the bottom of my file and obviously removing `export default` from in front of `class App...` and also pulling out `createAppContainer` from inside my `react-navigation`, I get an error that says:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set you createAppContainer like this

```
import AuthScreen from "./screens/AuthScreen";
import WelcomeScreen from "./screens/WelcomeScreen";
import MapScreen from "./screens/MapScreen";
import DeckScreen from "./screens/DeckScreen";
import SettingsScreen from "./screens/SettingsScreen";
import ReviewScreen from "./screens/ReviewScreen";
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

const MainNavigator = createAppContainer(createBottomTabNavigator({  // set createAppContainer here
    welcome: WelcomeScreen,
    auth: AuthScreen,
    main: {
    screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
        map: MapScreen,
        deck: DeckScreen,
        review: {
        screen: createStackNavigator({
            review: ReviewScreen,
            settings: SettingsScreen
        })
        }
    })
    }
}));

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MainNavigator />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```